# how to bind a click handler for a Button in cppwinrt

Tags: c++-winrt

according to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property
I'm writing the following code

```
/*cl /nologo /Yupch.h /bigobj /await /std:c++latest /EHsc /I. demo.cpp pch.obj /link /winmd /out:appx\App.exe /subsystem:console /appcontainer*/
struct MainPage : PageT<MainPage>
{
  MainPage()
  {
    Application::LoadComponent(*this, Uri(L"ms-appx:///MainPage.xaml"));
  }

  void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /* sender */, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& /* args */)
  {
    cout << __func__ << endl;
  }
};
```

and the MainPage.xaml page is as follow

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button Click="ClickHandler">click</Button>
</Page>
```

but it seems that the MainPage::ClickHandler never got called , so , what is the right way ? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your *MainPage.xaml* is missing an [x:Class attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-class-attribute) on the root `Page` declaration:

```xml
<Page x:Class="MyNamespace.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button Click="ClickHandler">click</Button>
</Page>
```

Without that attribute, the XAML platform doesn't know, where to look for the `ClickHandler` to bind to the `Click` event.

Comment: added 2 attributes ```xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="MainPage"``` , but did not work , got ```Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassNotDerivedFromElement'``` error

Comment: @old: I believe `x:Class` has to be the first attribute you specify.

Comment: @old: On a second thought, since your `MainPage` appears to be declared in global scope, I assume that you haven't provided a complementary IDL file describing your `MainPage` type. Again, not entirely sure, but I believe that XAML needs a .winmd file for code-gen, and IDL is the tool to have the build tools construct one for you.

Comment: a little progress : I add a ```GetRuntimeClassName``` method to ```MainPage```  ```auto GetRuntimeClassName()
  {
    return L"MainPage";
  }``` and implement IXamlMetadataProvider ```struct App : ApplicationT<App,IXamlMetadataProvider>``` this time ```GetXamlType``` get called with ```"MainPage"``` parameter, but it seems XAML does not do any further call to my ```IXamlType``` , but maybe this is the direction

Comment: sorry : ```IXamlType``` got called , I'll make it work correctly

Comment: When you added the GetRuntimeClassName method and implemented IXamlMetadataProvider, have you solved this issue?